# Broken links in content reports when tracking subdomains with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I have a tracking code that I use on my main site and my blog, which is on a subdomain:

- www.example.com
- blog.example.com

I have a single profile in Google Analytics.  I use advanced segments to look at traffic to the main site vs. traffic to the blog.

**Problem 1:**

When I'm browsing my content reports under Standard Reporting, the "Page" column doesn't show the top-level or sub-domain, so I can't differentiate `www.example.com/index.html` from `blog.example.com/index.html` easily.

According to the docs, [this filter](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#keyComponents) is supposed to make GA prepend the hostname to the page URL in your content reports, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Problem 2:**

When I click on the little "Open in new window" icon next to a given page in a content report line, it always assumes the page lives on `www.example.com`, so I get 404s when the page is actually on `blog.example.com`.

Is there a good solution for these subdomain tracking problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a good solution for these subdomain tracking problems?

Prepend the subdomain to the content URI in your tracking snippet - while this will not address your present tracking problems, it will create unique URI's for your subdomain (providing you don't *also* have a directory named "blog" under your primary domain) for all future tracking.

Tracking snippet example for `blog.example.com`:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

... becomes ...

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/blog' + window.location.pathname]);
```

If you want to simplify navigation between your analytics reports and content on your site, you can create permanent redirects for the `/blog` directory at `example.com`